# Max Token Limit for Azure GPT-4 Models

Tags: azure, openai-api, azure-openai, gpt-4

Why can I only set a maximum value of 8192 for deployment requests on Azure  gpt-4 32k (10000 TPM) and Azure gpt-4 1106-Preview (50000 TPM)? I thought I could set a higher value. Am I missing something in the configuration?
[image: This is image for gpt4-1106-Preview (50000 TPM)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `gpt4-preivew` is working similar to GPT 4 in playground. It's a UI Limitation as of now.

It means it is 8k input context in the playground, but it can really be given a 128k input via API.

One possible solution can be to use, `gpt-4-32k`.

[image]

Or you can use the `gpt4-preivew` with [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/reference) by which you can use 128k tokens.

For more details, you can check this [thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1433156/ive-noticed-that-the-knowdage-of-the-model-gpt-4-t) related to similar issue.

Comment: Thanks for info about limitations. I tried gpt 4 1106-Preview through rest api and still got the same error. While it worked fine for gpt-4 0613 using rest api.